# How to refer to object in anonymous sub when calling constructor?

Tags: perl, scope, anonymous-function, www-mechanize

```
$mech = new WWW::Mechanize(
    onerror => sub { 
        say "Failed to get " . $mech->uri  . ". Retrying.";
        $mech->get($mech->uri);
    }
);
```

How can I get the above code to work?  I want to refer to the URI that the Mechanize object just tried to get and then re-try, but I can't work out how to refer to this inside the call to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to solve this problem.  `WWW::Mechanize` wants a `croak`-compatible function here in order to be able to exit on fatal error.  It's going to pass a list of strings, and the `$mech` object won't be visible -- nor necessarily valid.

If you want to retry requests, put that logic around the requests with a `try` block.  If you want to generalize this to all requests, subclass `WWWM`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of other conditions besides a failed request that can trigger your `onerror` handler; in those cases, it doesn't make sense to send a new request.

You should catch exceptions thrown by `$mech->get` and re-throw any that aren't connection errors. You can do this in a subroutine:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use Try::Tiny;
use WWW::Mechanize;

sub retry {
    my ($mech, $uri, $options) = @_;

    $options //= {};

    my $method   = $options->{method}   // 'get';
    my $retries  = $options->{retries}  // 3;
    my $interval = $options->{interval} // 3;

    _try_request($mech, $uri, $method);

    while (! $mech->success && $retries-- > 0) {
        warn "Failed " . uc($method) . "ing $uri. Re-trying ...\n";
        sleep $interval;

        _try_request($mech, $uri, $method);
    }
}

sub _try_request {
    my ($mech, $uri, $method) = @_;

    try {
        $mech->$method($uri);
    }
    catch {
        die $_ unless /Can't connect/; # re-throw other errors
    };
}

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
retry($mech, 'http://www.stackoverflow.comx', { retries => 1 });
```

Output:

```
Failed GETing http://www.stackoverflow.comx. Re-trying ...
```

Alternatively, you can subclass WWW::Mechanize and override the request methods. That would save you from having to pass around the `$mech` object.

Comment: There's also [WWW::Mechanize::Plugin::Retry](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Plugin::Retry), but it appears to be broken.

Comment: This is the right way to retry, in my opinion  (this is what I do, just w/o `try`-ing). The exception handling is more to make sure to cover it all, right? It should work with only checking the object with its own methods?

Comment: @zdim By default, WWW::Mechanize dies on error, so you have to either turn off `autocheck` or trap exceptions. I'd rather leave `autocheck` on so the mech can still die automatically elsewhere in the code.

Comment: OK, right, forgot about that.  (In what I do I norally turn it off and handle errors.)